# Not Borel measurable set

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets

Do there exist non-Borel measurable sets?

I think not on $\mathbb{R}$ because open sets, closed sets, compact sets, and so on are Borel since they generate Borel.

Comment: Do you mean a set which is not Borel-measurable, or a set which is measurable but not Borel?

Answer (score -1):

If you use Axiom of choice, for all$y\in (a,b)$, there exists wellorder$<$ and
$$A:=\{(x,y) \in (a,b)^2| x<y\}$$
So assume continnum hypothesis, $A_y:=\{x\in (a,b)|x<y \}$ is countable set. Then, by $$\int \int 1_A dx dy =0$$,
$$\int \int 1_A dy dx=1$$
So, by Fubini's theorem, $A$ is not measurable.

Comment: The set $A$ depends on $y$, so I would suggest denoting that somehow (e.g. writing $A_y$). Either way, why would the second integral be $1$?

Comment: Sorry,I mistake. I have edited.

Comment: This is not correct - the axiom of choice is not enough here. Arbitrary well-order will not have the claimed properties. It has to have order type $\omega_1$, and such an order only exists if we assume the continuum hypothesis.